# Teradata 15: extracting number from STRING and putting it into DECIMAL

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to extract srings like this:

```
QQ_34_5
HHR_43_9
ET_7_25
```

into DECIMAL numbers, receiving this:

```
34,50
43,90
7,25
```

What is the correct function(s) ?

thx

Comment: Are those strings always formatted the same: `characters_digits_digits`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` and `TO_NUMBER`:

```
 To_Number(RegExp_Substr(col, '([0-9])+_([0-9])+$'), '9999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''_.''')
```

Comment: Plus one.  When I searched for `REGEXP_SUBSTRING` and Teradata your documentation came up :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '[A-Za-z0-9]+_([0-9])+_([0-9])+$', '\1,\2', 1, 0) AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

If you really need bona fide decimals, then you can cast the above output, e.g.

```
SELECT
    CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '[A-Za-z0-9]+_([0-9])+_([0-9])+$', '\1.\2', 1, 0)
         AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: thx, but result is incorrent: transforming "GTH_15_9" i received "59,0". What should be changed to get "15,90"?

Comment: @GrigoryP The missing zero is not significant.  Do you really need it there?  You can just cast to decimal and go from there.

Comment: Tim, missing zero is not a problem, but missing "1" is. I expected to receive "15.9" from  "GTH_15_9"

Comment: @GrigoryP I added an ending anchor `$` to the pattern.  Please try this.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can do that.

1) Using substring and instring.

2) Strtok function

```
strtok(colname, '_', 2)||','||strtok(colname, '_', 3)||'0'
```

3) Regex function